# Typescript - whichever type of those imported from a module

Tags: typescript, graphql

I have something like:

```
import * as Types from '../schema/types';
```

and I wanna do something like:

```
let a: Types;
```

indicating that `a` has to be one of the multiple types exported from `types.ts`. How can I do that? (Yes it's a graphql server)

Comment: Not a direct answer, so comment instead. Maybe this could help: https://github.com/dangcuuson/graphql-schema-typescript

Comment: we're using this one here: https://graphql-code-generator.com/, but thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are intention is to use `union types`. For typescript [`union types`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html) you can refer below sample example -

**Scenario 1: Construct individual types in other module and use union during the usage:**

**types.ts**

```
type a = {
    name: string;
}

type b ={
    name: number;
}

export type {a, b}
```

**You can use it like :**

```
import {a,b} from './types';

let a: a|b;
```

**Or**

```
import * as types from './types';

let a: types.a|types.b;
```

**Scenario 2: Construct union types in other module and use in calling side:**

**types.ts**

```
type a = {
    name: string;
}

type b ={
    id: string;
}

export type types = a|b
```

**Use it**

```
import {types}  from './types';

let a: types;
```

***For using the union types in `graphql` use the example mentioned [`here`](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#union-types) -***

**Update:** After seeing your comments regarding getting all the types the answer is **NO**. The `interfaces` and `types` fall under the `type space` which dont even exist in the `JS` world and they are just compiler hints for objects to have specific structure. In other words you even cannot do the `Object.Keys/ Object.entries` to get all the types from the module and assign them like you do in `classes.` These dont even exist in the run time.

Your best bet would be to extract them from the module and convert to `union types` or construct the union type in the types.ts file and use them in the main file.

Comment: like the answer from @smac89... i have plenty of them generated automatically, thus i'd need to have an automatic way to get them all into a union type

Comment: QQ- how are you exporting these automatically generated types form types.ts file?

Comment: export A = { ... } export B = { ... }

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way to do it automatically, but what you need is a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types).

Assuming you have the following types declared in the `../schema/types`:

```
interface Foo {
 ...
}

interface Bar {
 ...
}
```

imported with `import * as Types from '../schema/types';`

You can create a union type like:

```
type GqType = Types.Bar | Types.Foo;
```

Then you can create `a` like:

```
let a: GqType;
```

Comment: makes sense, but I'm afraid not for my case. I have tons of types that are also automatically generated..